# Reseting Password for Windows 7 or XP

Tags: windows, passwords

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows: How to reset the administrator password?](https://superuser.com/questions/5039/windows-how-to-reset-the-administrator-password)

Is there any option to bypass the login of Windows 7 or Win XP at login screen when it ask for the username and password?

Can we login without entering the Username and Password as a Admin?

Answer (score 0):

[MS article regarding auto-logon for Windows XP](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315231)

[If you're running Windows 7 in a domain](https://superuser.com/questions/28647/windows-7-automatic-login-when-on-a-domain)

Answer (score 0):

Blank passwords are the simplest method - if Windows 7 has ONE user, and that user has no password, you will not even be prompted. A username with a blank password cannot be used for remote login (by default) - but aside from that (beneficial) limitation, it's great for situations where you do not want or need a login.

I believe XP will still prompt for a login, but having a blank password also renders XP accounts ineligible for RDP.

In either case, you can use a user with administrative rights.