# Auto Relogon after remote access by admin

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop, user-accounts, domain, auto-login

I see this article about auto login when joined to a domain. [How do I enable Automatic Logon in Windows 7 when I'm on a domain?](https://superuser.com/questions/28647/windows-7-automatic-login-when-on-a-domain)

I have a similar scenario. But there is an occasion when a user may want to log on remotely and therefore lock out the workstation.

My question is. Once the remote user logs off will the station automatically log back in to the user setup in the link above?

Or alternatively is there a way to get windows 7 to allow concurrent logins that is not as crippling as it was when done to XP.I see this article on it http://www.windows7hacker.com/index.php/2009/09/how-to-enable-multiple-concurrent-user-in-remote-desktop-windows-7/ but was wondering if that would work in a domain? Though thats another question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, when a user logs out, it will not automatically log another user back in. That autologon only works when the winlogon process is starting on boot.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_NT_startup_process#Winlogon

That multiple logons hack may work, but it is not a supported configuration, and certainly a violation of the EULA.

Comment: As a follow up to this comment, Has anyone done multiple logons on Windows 7 that would like to share their experience? If it works fine then that is the answer I am looking for. Do remember this computer is on a domain.

Answer (score 0):

When you disconnect from the RDP session you can use this to send the session back to the "console" using this method your interactive scheduled scripts will still execute.

Disconnectx.bat ------

SET TEMPFILE="%TEMP%%RANDOM%.TXT"
query user %USERNAME% >%TEMPFILE%
for /f "usebackq skip=1 tokens=3" %%i in (%TEMPFILE%) do %windir%\System32\tscon.exe %%i /dest:console
del %TEMPFILE%