# How to make Windows login automatically to a user if there are more than one users?

Tags: windows-7

The system is `Windows7` 64-bit Integral Edition. There are two administrator users : Ambre-68 and postgres. When I start my computer then there is the screen showing the choice of users. I want `Windows` to login automatically to the user AMbre-68. How to do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to Start | run (or hit Win+R) and enter `control userpasswords2`. There should be an option called "users must enter a username and password to use this computer". I don't think it's available on domain PCs though. Un-check this option and you will be prompted to enter the details of the user you want to automatically log in.

[This question](https://superuser.com/questions/28647/how-do-i-enable-automatic-logon-in-windows-7-when-im-on-a-domain) addresses what to do if you're on a domain.